# I need to find a match using sed and deletes 2 lines before this match and 3 lines after it

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sed

I need to find a match using "sed" and deletes 2 lines before this match and 3 lines after it, and print the output , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

if the file is not huge, try this:

```
    awk 'NR==FNR{if($0~/matchWord/){for(i=NR-2;i<=NR+3;i++){if(i!=NR)a[i]++}}}\
NR>FNR{if(!(FNR in a))print $0}' file file
```

I didn't test, but should work.

Comment: thanks Kent this is working, but do u know how to do this using sed ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you do not want to do this in sed.  2nd, your question is ill posed: what do you do if you have a match on lines 5 and 8?  Does line 8 get deleted and line 6 is kept?  Assuming that's not a concern, this seems to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

1{ h; d; } 
H
2,5d
g
/^\([^\n]*\n\)\{2\}match/!P
/^\([^\n]*\n\)\{2\}match/{
  s/\n[^\n]*$//
  N
}
s/[^\n]*\n//
h
$p
```

Note: if the match occurs in the last 3 lines of the file, this does not behave as desired.  That case is left as an exercise for the (masochistic) reader.

Comment: I see that I misread your question (based on your statement that Kent's solution does what you want.)  This deletes exactly one line two lines before the match and exactly one line 3 lines after the match.  Do you want to delete 6 lines total for each match?  That's actually easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ‘/matchWord/,+3d;:flag;1,2!{P;N;D};N;bflag’ file
```